# $V=W\oplus U=U\oplus X=W\oplus X$. Show there is a $2$ dim subspace $A\subseteq V$ s.t. each of $A\cap W, A\cap U$ and $A\cap X$ has dimension $1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Question: Let $V$ be a vector space with subspaces $W,U, X$ such that $V=W\oplus U=U\oplus X=W\oplus X$.  Prove there is a $2$ dimensional subspace $A\subseteq V$ such that each of $A\cap W, A\cap U$ and $A\cap X$ has dimension $1$.

Thoughts: I figured we could fix bases $\{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$, $\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$, and $\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$ for $W, U, X$, respectively such that $\dim W=k$, $\dim U=n$, and $\dim X=m$.  Now, as $V=W\oplus U=U\oplus X=W\oplus X$, we have that $W\cap U=\{0\}$, $U\cap X=\{0\}, W\cap X=\{0\}$ (not sure if this helps, but since I want $A\cap\text{one of the subspaces}$ to have dimension $1$, I thought it might.  I suppose Rank-Nullity may help here, but I wasn't quite seeing how.  Maybe I should choose some two dimensional subspace $A$ of $V$, and then show the intersection stuff?  I am just a bit stuck on how to do that.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

P.S. Could this be extended further to more than $3$ subspaces?  Would the dimension of the intersection of $A$ and each subspace have to be adjusted?

Comment: Note we need $V \neq 0$ to avoid this singular counterexample...

Comment: Ah, yes :)  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First show that $W\neq 0$ by assuming $W=0$.  This implies $X=V=U$ which would imply $V = 0$ (which presumably should be disallowed, otherwise we have a counterexample).

Let $w \in W$ be nonzero.  Then $$w = w + 0 \in W \oplus U = U \oplus X,$$
so that there are $u \in U, x \in X$ such that $w = u + x$.

Also, $u \neq 0$, because if $u=0$, then we'd have $w = x \in X$ so $w \in X \cap W = \{0\}$, contradicting $w \neq 0$.  For a similar reason, it follows that $x \neq 0$.

Now set $A = \operatorname{span}\{w, u\}$.

By construction, we immediately have $\operatorname{span}\{w\}, \operatorname{span}\{u\}, \operatorname{span}\{x\} \subseteq A$ so that $A\cap W, A\cap U, A\cap X$ all have dimension at least 1.

None has dimension $\geq 2$.  For instance, if $A\cap W \subseteq A$ had dimension $\geq 2$, then we'd have $A\cap W = A$ and therefore $u \in A\cap U \subseteq W\cap U = \{0\},$ which contradicts $u \neq 0$.

---

With regard to your postscript, it's not even clear how you intend to extend the problem to a larger number of subspaces.  For instance, if you wanted to assume $$V = W_1\oplus W_2 = W_2\oplus W_3 = \ldots = W_{n-1} \oplus W_n = W_n \oplus W_1,$$ then the argument in my very first paragraph only works for $n$ odd.  For $n$ even, you run into the problem that the sequence might just alternate $0, V, 0, V, \ldots$ so of course there's no one-dimensional subspace of $0$.

I've not thought about whether $n=5$ or higher odd values of $n$ might work.

Comment: If we assume $W=0$, don't we get the contradiction immediately by the assumption in my second line?

Comment: @User7238 I don't know where your second line is.  There's no single basic assumption in the problem that implies $W \neq 0$, so I'm apt to say "no, we don't get the contradiction immediately."  Rather, $W\neq 0$ follows from the assumptions that $V\neq 0$ and $V$ splits over an odd-length cycle of subspaces.  If either assumption were removed, we'd not be able to conclude $W\neq 0$.  I will grant it's a simple argument, but I don't see an alternate method, at least from first principles.

Comment: When you say "V splits over an odd-length cycle of subspaces", do you mean since $V=W\oplus U=U\oplus X=W\oplus X$?  If $V$ split over a cycle of even-length subspaces, why would that not imply $W\neq 0$?

Comment: @User7238 Yes, that's what I mean.  As I mention in my response to your postscript, if you had, for instance
$$V = W_1 \oplus W_2 = W_2 \oplus W_3 = W_3 \oplus W_4 = W_4\oplus W_1$$ then you can have $W_1 = W_3 = 0$ and $W_2 = W_4 = V$.  This alternating of $0$ and $V$ is disallowed in the current problem because there are three subspaces in the cycle.

Comment: VERY COOL!  Thank you so much!  That all makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2):

Say $U\oplus W= V$ direct internal sum. A subspace $X$  such that $X\oplus W = V$ "is" the graph of a linear function $\phi \colon U\to W$. If we moreover want $X\oplus U = X$ then $\phi$ has to be bijective.

So now we have $U\oplus W = V$, $\phi\colon U\to W$ linear isomorphism and $X = \{u \oplus \phi(u)\ | u \in U\}$.

To get your subspace $A$: take $u\ne 0$ in $U$ and consider $A= \langle u, \phi(u)\rangle$. We have $A\cap U = \langle u\rangle$, $A\cap W = \langle \phi(u)\rangle$, $A \cap X = \langle u + \phi(u) \rangle$.